# Get popularity of track (spotipy)

Tags: python, spotipy

How could I get the popularity of a single track from its ID using spotipy?

For example, I have the following song id: 6YNuS3tJfip0Xqw9Ixzint. How could I get its popularity using spotipy?

I've found methods to get the popularity of all tracks in a playlist, but none to get the popularity of a single song (and I'm struggling to do it myself). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Popularity is one of the fields available in the [Track object](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-track), so you can simply retrieve it from the output of spotipy.track() method:

```py
track = sp.track("6YNuS3tJfip0Xqw9Ixzint")
popularity = track["popularity"]
```

where **sp** is your initialized Spotipy client